# Full ASM code example (only analysis)

Tags: jvm, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

Are there any good end-to-end ASM example but just for parsing and analysing bytecode? I have found a lot of examples involving bytecode generation, but what about just analysis like, data-flow analysis or control-flow analysis?

Comment: What kind of parsing are you looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

**Javassist:**

I would suggest you to have a look at [Javassist](http://www.javassist.org), espacially [javassist.bytecode.analysis](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/index.html).

This contains classes for

- [data flow analysis](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/bytecode/analysis/Analyzer.html),
- [control flow analysis](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/bytecode/analysis/ControlFlow.html)
- as well as multiple other tasks.

Javassist is pretty good documented, so it should be no problem to get into it.

Comment: Isnt this only for dynamic analsys? Can it run on classes read as files (outside of the JVM execution env). All the others can but each have some limitations or the other to achieve what op wants

Comment: @Allohvk Javassist can be used to a variety of ways. You can analyze class files (without modifying them), manipulate class files, or even generate new classes on the fly. Just read the docs, they explain most things very well. So yes, you can analyze classes read as files using Javassist that are "outside of your running JVM's execution environment".

Answer (score 2):

ASM is tool for bytecode generation. If you are interesed in data/flow analysis you should look on :

- Soot (https://sable.github.io/soot )
- Chord (http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~naik/chord.html )
- JavaPathFinder (http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki, https://jpf.byu.edu/ )

Those are programs designed to analyze bytecode. In asm you probably must implement most of analyze part by you own.

But you must decide which program is suitable for you goals.

Comment: Thanks, I have already considered Soot and Chord, I didn't look to JavaPathFinder although a colleague suggested it too. The thing is that the kind of analysis I am interested is pretty ad-hoc so I have to implement it, so far I noticed that ASM is the most flexible library, but it lacks of some documentation/examples for the analysis part. Since it is open source I am currently trying to figure things out from its code.

Comment: In addition to these tools I have also seen OPAL: http://www.opal-project.de/ it is a Scala library but it can also be used from Java. It looks very promising too.

Comment: @AbelGarcia It would help if you give us example what you want to achieve :)